# how can I run java package using the Unix command line?

Tags: java, unix, command, package

Given that I have the following file structure,

[image]

Anybody know what Unix commands to run the java project or any resources I can look up in order to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

For compiling both the java files:

```
EatInTime-SpringBootGrab_Data>javac -d "classes" "src/main/java/DataGrabber/Serial.java"

EatInTime-SpringBootGrab_Data>javac -d "classes" -classpath "src/main/java/DataGrabber/Main.java"
```

For Executing Main:

```
EatInTime-SpringBootGrab_Data>java -classpath "classes" main.java.DataGrabber.Main
```

Hope this helps.